# create a button by Extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View not show the button

Tags: orders, overrides, sales-order, extend

I'm trying to add a button on sales order view.but nothing appears.
this is my block in my config.xml

PMC_Manutention_Block_Adminhtml
       
       
                                   PMC_Manutention_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View

---

and my file view in PMC/Manutention/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/View.php

class PMC_Manutention_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View
{

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();


    if ($this->_isAllowedAction('reorder')
    ) {
        $orderId = $this->getOrderId();
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
        $shipment = $order->getShipmentsCollection()->getFirstItem();
        if($order->hasShipments()){
            $this->_addButton('order_printSticker', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Sticker'),
                'onclick'   => 'setLocation(\'' . $this->getPrintStickerUrl() . '\')',
                'class'     => 'go'
            ));
        }
    }

}


/**
 * add by ismo
 * Return back url for view grid
 *
 * @return string shipment_id
 */
public function getPrintStickerUrl()
{
    $orderId = $this->getOrderId();
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
    $shipment = $order->getShipmentsCollection()->getFirstItem();

    return $this->getUrl('*/sales_order_shipment/sticker', array('shipment_id'  => $shipment->getEntityId()));
}
```

}

Comment: What have you done to debug? `Mage::log($order);`